# how to "decdump" a string in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, hexdump

I need to convert a string into a sequence of decimal ascii code using bash command.

**example**:
for the string '**abc**' the desired output would be **979899** 
where a=97, b=98 and c=99 in ascii decimal code.

I was able to achieve this with ascii hex code using xxd.

```
printf '%s' 'abc' | xxd -p
```

which gives me the result: **616263**

where a=61, b=62 and c=63 in ascii hexadecimal code.

Is there an equivalent to xxd that gives the result in ascii decimal code instead of ascii hex code?

Comment: What do you think about the punctuation? The character "u" and followings are represented in three digits in decimal. If they are once merged into a straight string, you cannot retrieve the original sequence of characters.

Comment: Actually I don't need to retrieve the original sequence of characters. I need to replicate an algorithm made in java into shell script, one of the steps of the java algorithm do the same thing as I asked here.

Comment: [`xxd(1)` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xxd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the results are merged into a line, please try the following:

```
echo -n "abc" | xxd -p -c 1 |
while read -r line; do
    echo -n "$(( 16#$line ))"
done
```

Result:

```
979899
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying some options here, to check which one fits better for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

## Unicode Solution

What makes this problem annoying is that you have to pipeline characters when converting from hex to decimal. So you can't do a simple conversion from char to hex to dec as some characters hex representations are longer than others.

Both of these solutions are compatible with unicode and use a character's code point. In both solutions, a newline is chosen as separator for clarity; change this to `''` for no separator.

### Bash

```sh
sep='\n'
charAry=($(printf 'abc' | grep -o .))
for i in "${charAry[@]}"; do
  printf "%d$sep" "'$i"
done && echo
97
98
99
127926
```

### Python (in Bash)

Here, we use a list comprehension to convert every character to a decimal number (ord), join it as a string and print it. `sys.stdin.read()` allows us to use Python inline to get input from a pipe. If you replace `input` with your intended string, this solution is then cross-platform.

```py
printf '%s' 'abc' | python -c "
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
sep = '\n'
print(sep.join([str(ord(i)) for i in input]))"
97
98
99
127926
```

Edit: If all you care about is using hex regardless of encoding, use @user1934428's answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm trying some options here, to check which one fits better for my solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
str=abc
printf '%s' $str | od -An -tu1
```

The -An gets rid of the address line, which od normally outputs, and the -tu1 treats each input byte as unsigned integer. Note that it assumes that one character is one byte, so it won't work with Unicode, JIS or the like.

If you really don't want spaces in the result, pipe it further into `tr -d ' '`.